# How to submit form jsp to controller?

Tags: spring, jsp

In my jsp there are two fields: 1 types of documents and 2 are statuses.
The challenge is that I can send the selection to my controller. I can not figure out jsp how to send by action these values ​​at the click of a button

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card">
        <div id="collapseSearchParams" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingSearchParams" >
            <div class="card-body">

                <form:form  action="${request.contextPath}/search"  method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label semibold" for="typeCode">${phDocType}</label>

                                <select class="form-control" id="typeCode">                                     
                                    <c:forEach var="type" items="${documentList}">
                                        <option id = "${type.value}"> ${type.name} </ option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                </select>                                
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label semibold" for="statusCode">${phOrderStatus}</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="statusCode">                                     

                                    <option> A</ option>
                                    <option> B</option>
                                    <option> C</option>
                                    <option> D</option>
                                </select>                                
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button id ="btnSearchUsers" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="float: right; "><span class="fa fa-search"></span> <spring:message code="label.button.search" /></button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get this data in the controller to process? What changes should I make in jsp and in the method?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/perso")
public class PersoController {
@Autowired
private PersoService persoService;

private List<DocumentType> docTypeList = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
public String persoList(Principal principal, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    docTypeList = persoService.persoList(authentication, principal);

    model.addAttribute("documentList", docTypeList);
    return "admin/perso/list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void searchOrders( ){

}

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.java4s.com/java-servlet-tutorials/example-of-request-getparameter-retrieve-parameters-from-html-form/

Comment: You do use servlets, you just don't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use @RequestParam in your controller.

For Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar")
public String testAction(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
    //Do whatever you want to fieldName
    return "view";
}
```

**For your case**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void searchOrders(@RequestParam String statusCode ,@RequestParam String typeCode)
{

 //Do whatever you want

}
```

Comment: the button does not work when pressed to send this data

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы Your button is not a submit button, so you have add an extra javascript that will do it for you.

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы you must add type="submit" to your button tag

Comment: please help with js code. What should code look like? i don't know js

Comment: or can do without js?

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp  or you can use https://www.formget.com/javascript-submit-form/